# Unit testing angular directive replaced by textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Hi I have this directive definition which is replaced by a textarea. It looks something like this:

```
angular.module('xyz')
.directive('dir1', [function()
{
    return {
        scope : {},
        replace : true,
        template : "<textarea></textarea>",
        require : "ngModel",
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl)
        {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value)
            {
                //..do some stuff
                return value;
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Now the problem is that I can't really test the branch inside the `ctrl.$parsers`. I tried so many different things. It is easy when it is a form so I just do something like `scope.input_form.input_value.$setViewValue('abcd')` and the model gets updated and so on. This case is just really difficult to reach the $parsers. The bit that is `//..do some stuff` is quite long and has a few corner cases and it is not feasible to test it via trial and error. Can anyone help? I will provide more details if this isn't clear.

UPDATE:

So the unit test is something like this:

```
describe('Specs for dir1', function()
{
    var scope, dir_1;
    beforeEach(module('xyz'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope)
    {
         scope = $rootScope.$new();
         scope.test_data = "";
         dir_1 = $compile("<dir1 ng-model='test_data'></dir1>")(scope);
    }));

    it('Does some stuff in $parsers when view value changes', function()
    {
        //I want to do something like this:
        //<textarea>.setViewValue("some value") which will
        //call one of the functions injected in $parsers.
    });
});
```

BTW you can be rest assured that the function injected in $parsers does get invoked when I try it out in the browser i.e. on rendered html when I type something into the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are *unit* testing your code, you want to try to isolate the different pieces into easily testable units.  You mention that `//..do some stuff` is quite complex. To me, this is screaming out to be refactored into a service, which can be easily testable itself since you can control the inputs and outputs.

If `//..do some stuff` interacts with the DOM and does lots of funky things with side-effects, that is a bad code smell and seems like it should be refactored to have fewer side-effects.

Once you have `//..do some stuff` properly extracted and unit tested, all you need for your test in your controller is that the `$parser` is correctly added, which is a much simpler test.

Comment: I was actually thinking something like that but was a bit too lazy to extract it out. Thank you for the suggestion. I will actually try it out now. Btw quick follow on question from this. How do I get the $parsers list in unit test to see if the function was added?

Comment: I was thinking of adding ctrl to the isolated scope for access.

Comment: Take a look at the $controller service. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller